# How can I join one tables row as other tables column to use as dynamic values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables my_user and custom_values.
One is user registration and other is custom variables.

I'm trying to create a query to use custom_values's row as result table's column like below.
[image]

Here is the query I wrote. Is there better way(better performance or cleaner code) to get same result?

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  (SELECT VALUE FROM CUSTOM_VALUES val WHERE PROP_NAME = 'age' AND usr.id = val.USER_ID) "age",
  (SELECT VALUE FROM CUSTOM_VALUES val WHERE PROP_NAME = 'gender' AND usr.id = val.USER_ID) "gender"
FROM
  my_user usr
;
```

sample datas.

```sql
CREATE TABLE  "MY_USER" (
  "ID" VARCHAR2(4000) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(4000) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP"
);

insert into MY_USER VALUES (1, 'Mike');
insert into MY_USER VALUES (2, 'John');
insert into MY_USER VALUES (3, 'Mike');

CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOM_VALUES" (
  "USER_ID"     VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
  "PROP_NAME"   VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
  "VALUE"       VARCHAR2(20) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP"
);

insert into custom_values VALUES(1, 'age', 18);
insert into custom_values VALUES(1, 'gender', 'male');
insert into custom_values VALUES(2, 'age', 24);
insert into custom_values VALUES(2, 'gender', 'male');
insert into custom_values VALUES(3, 'gender', 'male');
```

Comment: You could pivot CUSTOM_VALUES then join it https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php or you could perform conditional aggregation. You could even rewrite the current query as N joins (though I doubt this would be faster than what you have; oracle probably realises the two queries are equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of MAX(case <>) logic to build these kind of queries.

But i would suggest you rethink the datamodel you have, this will mostly lead to more complex queries if you need to write multiple conditional logic.

```
   select a.ID 
         ,max(a.name) as name
         ,max(case when PROP_NAME='age' then VALUE end) as age
         ,max(case when PROP_NAME='gender' then VALUE end) as gender
     from MY_USER a
     join CUSTOM_VALUES b
       on a.ID=b.USER_ID
 group by a.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ff176d0749e05ca4699f44e8c845dcc

Comment: Thanks to respond @George Joseph. Your query looks much cleaner than I wrote.
I'm new in this project and the original tables are really big now.. So it's quite difficult to change the datamodel